# Problems involving separation of X

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I dont understand what separation of X means here, $X = U \cup V$ means $x \in X$ is a subset of $U \cup V$, and the opposite also holds true. Y is a connected subset of X for $Y \subset X$ iff its in the subspace topology of X. then how do I show if they are separated, $Y \cup U$ or $Y \cup V$ ?
Do I need to do all the cases/possibilities for this?

It would be great if someone helps me. Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y=(Y\cap U) \cup (Y\cap V)$. The sets $Y\cap U$ and $Y\cap V$ are disjoint open subsets of $Y$ so one of them must be empty. If the first one is empty then $Y \subseteq V$ and if the second one is empty then $Y \subseteq U$.

Comment: thanks for posting this, I don't understand how you arranged Y to be the union of two disjoint open subsets (Y $\cap$ U) and (Y $\cap$ U). Can you please explain that? Also, if one of the open subsets are empty, how can we say that Y is a subset of V else the other one is empty ?

Comment: For first question: verify that each side is contained in the other. For second question: if $y \in Y$ and $U \cap U$ is empty than $y \in U \cup V$ and $y$ cannot be in $U$ so $y \in Y$. Hence $Y \subseteq V$. Simaialr argument when $V \cap U$ is empty. @Math_Is_Fun

Comment: I got the 1st one, its a set theoretic relation. From that you are getting this which is fine, but in the second part, (if y∈Y and U∩U is empty than y∈U∪V and y cannot be in U so y∈Y. Hence Y⊆V), shouldn't it be if y $\in$ (Y $\cap$ U), then y $\in$ Y and y $\in$ U ? How come you got U intersect U? Also, why y cannot be in U ?

Comment: $U$ intersect $U$ was  typo. It was supposed to be $Y \cap U$. If $y \in Y$ and $Y\cap U=\emptyset$ the $y$ cannot be in $U$ right? That will force $y$ to be in $V$ because any point of $Y$ belongs to one of the sets $U,V$. @Math_Is_Fun

Comment: yeah, now I got you. Now its crystal clear. Thanks a lot.